# Solving over-constrained, nonlinear system of equations in python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I need to solve a 3x3 matrix of equations for three variables: alpha, beta, and gamma. The matrix of equations corresponds to another 3x3 matrix of values for each equation, named `rot` in the example code. I have been trying to use `scipy.optimize.fsolve` and a few other non-linear solvers but keep running into the issue that the input size, 3 corresponding to alpha, beta, and gamma is different than the output size.

```
def solveNonLinear(rot):
    #The function of alpah beta and gamma
    def F(vals):
        a = vals[0]
        b = vals[1]
        y = vals[2]
        #matrix of equations
        r = [math.cos(b)*math.cos(y) + math.sin(a)*math.sin(b)*math.sin(y),
             math.cos(a)*math.sin(y),
             math.cos(b)*math.sin(a)*math.sin(y) - math.sin(b)*math.cos(y),
             math.sin(a)*math.sin(b)*math.cos(y) - math.cos(b)*math.sin(y),
             math.cos(a)*math.cos(y),
             math.sin(b)*math.sin(y) + math.cos(b)*math.sin(a)*math.cos(y),
             math.cos(a)*math.sin(b),
             -1*math.sin(a),
             math.cos(a)*math.cos(b)]


        diff = np.array(r) - np.ravel(rot)
        return diff

    x = scipy.optimize.fsolve(F, [0, 0, 0])
    return x
```

In my function above `a`, `b`, and `y` correspond to alpha, beta, and gamma respectively. The error that I get is `TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'F'.` In matlab this can be done with three inputs and nine outputs. I am looking for a way that I can solve this with three inputs and nine outputs, not changing the number of outputs, all of the constraints are necessary.

Comment: leastsq does solve without giving errors but it is giving similar approximation problems to a different method we've tried where we partially solved by hand. The system has multiple solutions and the least squares regression isn't giving us the one we'd like.

Comment: (Sorry - deleted my comment suggesting scipy.optimize.leastsq - I had a slight loss of faith!)

Comment: My only other suggestion then is to try different starting points (for leastsq) but hopefully someone else can suggest something better.

Comment: That's a good idea, we are using this in a real time joint angle generation so I guess a good starting point would be the last known joint angles.

Comment: @DavidW `scipy.optimize.leastsq` with the better guess seems to be working well enough for our purposes. Thanks!